# Linq error: can't group

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is a Linq query:

```
Common.ProductType.ProductTypeEnum[] aCustomerProduct = 
    (from customer in repositoryCustomer.GetAll().Where(cp => cp.Email == strEmail)
    join cp in repositoryCustomerProduct.GetAll() on customer.CustomerId equals cp.CustomerId
    select cp.ProdId
    ).ToArray<ProductType.ProductTypeEnum>();
```

Everything is working fine here: the array of 4 items is returned.

But here I need to receive a unique items only, so I've added grouping here:

```
Common.ProductType.ProductTypeEnum[] aCustomerProduct = 
    (from customer in repositoryCustomer.GetAll().Where(cp => cp.Email == strEmail)
    join cp in repositoryCustomerProduct.GetAll() on customer.CustomerId equals cp.CustomerId
    group cp by cp.ProdId into products0
    select products0.Key
    ).ToArray<ProductType.ProductTypeEnum>();
```

And instead of array I've got an error message:

> The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'Common.ProductType+ProductTypeEnum'. Actual 'System.Int32'.

What is wrong with the 2nd query?

Please advise. Thanks a lot!

P.S. The 2nd query doesn't go to MSSQL server at all (Profiler shows nothing for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you grouping just for uniqueness? Why not just use distinct?

```
(from **blah
join **blaa
select **blah).Distinct().ToArray();
```

This will produce much more eficient SQL.

Comment: Agree with that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have grouped by `ProdId` as the key and then selected the key. So if `ProdId` is an integer then your query is returning `IEnumerable<int>`. You then won't be able to implicitly change to an array of type `ProductType.ProductTypeEnum`.

Comment: Method 'GetAll()' for my repository class returns object and 'ProdId' field of CustomerProduct object is of 'Common.ProductType.ProductTypeEnum' type. This shouldn't prevent from grouping... But... probably you are right: grouping is done on the SQL-server side and there ProdId is really integer... thanks. Will check.

Comment: But... actually, Linq tells me that products0.Key is actually of 'Common.ProductType.ProductTypeEnum' type...